# Retrieve data from xml file to WebBrowser

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, winforms

I have this xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
<root>
  <radio>
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <url>https://www.google.com</url>

  </radio>
  <radio>
    <title>The Autobiography of n Franklin</title>
    <url>https://www.facebook.com</url>

  </radio>
  <radio>
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjaminin</title>
    <url>https://www.yahoo.com</url>

  </radio>

</root>
```

I displayed the title tag in the combobox by this code :

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("books.xml")
Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title")
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To elemList.Count - 1
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(elemList(i).InnerXml)
    Next i
```

So I want when the user clicks on the title in the combobox the web browser Navigate to the url that is linked with the title in the xml file.

Comment: What did you try, what is the problem you're facing? Can you retrieve the selected item from the combobox? Can you find the right url with the right item from the combobox? Can you load the specific url in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

C#

Load xml to anonymous type list. Bind it to combobox.

```
var xmlDoc = XElement.Load("books.xml");

var nodes = xmlDoc.Elements("radio")
    .Select(elem => new
    {
        Title = elem.Element("title").Value,
        Url = elem.Element("url").Value
    })
    .ToList();

comboBox.DisplayMember = "Title";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Url";
comboBox.DataSource = nodes;
```

Navigate to url.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser.Navigate(comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```